# Minishift: The route is not accepting traffic yet because it has not been admitted by a router

Tags: openshift, minishift

I would like to try openshift by installing minishift in my PC in Windows platform.
I successfully create a project and application. And the container pod is running.

I can also create a route to expose the application to outside.
However, when accessing the application from outside by the route, it is not successful.
Checking the route status, it always saying:

> The route is not accepting traffic yet because it has not been admitted by a router.

and this keeps a very long time.
How to resolve this issue?
I am using minishift version 1.7.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Can you try minishift v1.14.0 again? What steps  you were using when you got this error?

Comment: @ram when I use newer version 1.18.0, there is no problem